# Complex unitary matrix's geometric interpretation

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, linear-transformations, numerical-linear-algebra

Is it valid to think of complex unitary matrix as some rotation in complex vector space analogous to real unitary matrix as some rotation in real vector space? The reason I ask this is because I tired to find a 2x2 complex unitary matrix which can perform certain rotation to vectors in C2 space, specifically, I want to rotation [a1+i0, a2+i0]^T to [0+i0, a3+ib]^T (rotate a vector in the R2 subspace of C2 to C1 subspace of C2). I thought i was possible because if you think of imaginary axis just as additional dimension, this rotation would have no difference from rotating a vector in R4 which initially in a R2 subspace to another R2 subspace. But the numerical method I used suggested me such a 2x2 complex unitary matrix does not exist.

Comment: No. Orthogonal transformations in $\mathbb{R}^4$ (i.e. rotations and reflections) satisfy $A^TA=I$, which does not become $A^*A=I$ when you rewrite them as transformations in $\mathbb{C}^2$. There are many more $\mathbb{R}^4$ rotations.

Comment: By 'no' do you mean complex unitary matrix cannot be interpreted  as rotation in complex space?

Comment: It can, see [What's the interpretation of a unitary matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/204206/152568) But there are rotations not representable by such matrices, including the one you want.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that [0+i0, a3+ib]^T has the same norm defined as inner product of complex vectors (conjugate transpose of one vector dot with another) as [a1+i0, a2+i0]^T. So if assuming they have the same norm, why I cannot map the first one to the second one by some rotation?